# Getting "Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<*> is not assignable to parameter of type 'Action<any>" when using custom typed useAppDispatch hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

A working example in [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-v9nq5?file=/src/information.component.tsx).

I'm starting the development of a React application using TypeScript and Redux Toolkit. I followed the instructions in the Redux Toolkit documentation about how to use it with TypeScript. So, I have typed versions of `State` (`RootState` type) and Dispatch (`AppDispatch` type)

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    information: informationReducer,
  },
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Also, I'm trying to use typed versions of `appDispatch` (`useAppDispatch`).

```
export const useAppDispatch = (): ReturnType<typeof useDispatch> =>
  useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

The problem is I'm getting an error saying

> Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<string, void, ThunkAPi>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Action'

when calling an async thunk using the return of `useAppDispatch`:

```
export const Information: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const appDispatch = useAppDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    appDispatch(fetchInformation()); // error occurs here
  });

  return <p>An awesome information component</p>;
};
```

My thunk is created using `createAsyncThunk`:

```
type ThunkAPi = {
    rejectValue: string;
};

export const fetchInformation = createAsyncThunk<string, void, ThunkAPi>(
    "information/fetchInformation",
    async (_, thunkAPi) => {
        const result = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        if (result > 3) {
            return Promise.resolve("resolved");
        }

        return thunkAPi.rejectWithValue("rejected");
    }
);
```

I don't know why, but the error disappears when I remove the type of `useAppDispatch`. That is, using this way:

```
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

instead of:

```
export const useAppDispatch = (): ReturnType<typeof useDispatch> =>
      useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

Also, the error disappears when I use the standard hook `useDispatch` instead of the custom typed `useAppDispatch`.

So, my question is: Why is this error occurring? Seems that all my type system is right... I looked for similar issues and found nothing that solves my problem.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specifically documented at https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript#define-typed-hooks , the correct definition is:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

Your example says that it returns the "return type of `useDispatch`", which is the plain un-augmented/non-thunk-aware `Dispatch` type. That definitely won't work.

Not sure why you're trying to do something different for `useAppDispatch` - please use the correct definition as shown there.

Comment: Hi @markerikson. Thank you for your help! So, are you saying that there is no way to define a type for `useAppDispatch`? I'm only trying to define a type for it because I prefer to use explicit function return types and enabled the eslint rule `@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type`.

Comment: that type would be `() => AppDispatch` - but a lot of RTK is created in a way so that you specifically should not manually assign types to it, as you will lose valuable type information and get a subpar development experience that way.